# Cannot pass parameter with near call

Tags: nearprotocol, near

I'm testing the Greeting contract in "workshop--exploring-assemblyscript-contracts" and try to pass parameter to saveMyMessage function but always get error. There maybe problem with quotations marks, I tried with " or '` but nothing succeeds. I'm running it on Windows.
This is the suggestion from the code:

> near call greeting..testnet saveMyMessage '{"message": "bob? you in there?"}' --account-id .testnet

When I try

> near call %ID% saveMyMessage '{"message": "bob? you in there?"}' --account-id %ID%

Or replace " with " or end single quote with ` always get error like this

> Unknown argument: bob? you in there?}'

Comment: I've encountered the same problem. Were you able to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

For starters, it appears you have a syntax error with 2 dots instead of 1 here - greeting..testnet

Have you tried seeing what `%ID%` is?

I would try the following syntax, but make sure when you set your `ID`env variable, that it returns the correct value when you run `echo $ID`

Once you have your env variables set up correctly, try the following:

```
near call $ID saveMyMessage '{"message": "bob? you in there?"}' --account-id $ID
```